# Postman operators giving assertions errors

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, postman, operators

How can i use

```
pm.test("Response has child or adult",function(){
  pm.expect(pm.response.json().data[0].attributes.assessments[1].awards[0].awardComponents[0].type).eql('child' || 'adult');
```

The json is

```
"awards": [{
        "startDate": "2021-05-02",
        "endDate": "2021-06-01",
        "status": "live",
        "takeHomePay": 43501,
        "awardComponents": [{
                "type": "female",
                "componentAwardAmount": 59658
            }, {
                "type": "child",
                "componentAwardAmount": 59658
            }
        ],
```

I am getting this error `AssertionError: expected 'standard_allowance' to deeply equal 'child_element'`

Comment: `The json is` incomplete or invalid

Comment: just looking at it you can see that `.awards[0].awardComponents[0].type` ... is `"female"` - which is neither `"child"` nor `"adult"`